# java 11 can not add as jre in spring tool suite version 3.9.7

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, java-11

I am trying to run a simple spring boot project with java 11 but I can not add it as jre. I am getting following error while adding it as jre
[image]

I am using following java version on maco os 10.13.16

```
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I tried to use the similar path( Contents/Home/lib) for jdk10 and it recognised as jre 10. I think that STS is not able to read **jrt-fs.jar** for java 11.

Can somebody pleas give some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JRE home for Java 11.0.2 on macOS is

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

(no 'lib' at the end)

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I reached home, I will check and let you know whether the solution works or not